# Magento front end links not working

Tags: magento, url, hyperlink

I am trying to create a test environment for a Magento site. I downloaded all the files and the database and restored to XAMPP. I changed the two base urls in the core_config_data table to http://magento.local/magento/ and modified the Magento config file to connect to the local database. I also added magento.local in the hosts file. I'm using magento.local as I read Magento must have a . in the domain name. The site almost works except on the front end when on http://magento.local/magento/ and try and go to a different page it tries to access http://magento.local/pagename/ and gives a 404 error, i can access through http://magento.local/magento/index.php/pagename. I have also disabled Web Server Rewrites in the backend as I read that is supposed to fix this problem. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: After disabling the url rewrites clear the cache. But in order to make it work with url rewrites enable `mod_rewrite` on your server.

Comment: i cleared the cache and went back on the site and it filled the cache again but the links are still broken. does it mean my servers url rewrites are working if the cache filled again or could the issue be my server configuration?

Comment: The cache should be filled in again with the new values. I think it's a problem with your server configuration